# Is there a way to count unique pairs and group by other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find the number of unique combinations in each Station by year. My data looks like this:

| Track Title | Main Artist | Station | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Track A | Artist A | A | 2020 |
| Track A | Artist A | A | 2020 |
| Track B | Artist A | A | 2020 |
| Track B | Artist A | A | 2020 |
| Track A | Artist B | A | 2020 |
| Track A | Artist B | A | 2020 |
| Track B | Artist B | A | 2020 |
| Track B | Artist B | A | 2020 |
| Track A | Artist A | A | 2019 |
| Track A | Artist A | A | 2019 |
| Track A | Artist A | A | 2019 |

I need just a count of each unique combination of Track Title and Main Artist per station per year:

| Count | Station | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | A | 2020 |
| 1 | A | 2019 |

I am on a SQL Server using SSMS.

The closest I had gotten to the result before was

```
SELECT 
    Count(distinct [Track Title]) as Count,
        [Main Artist],
        [Station Code]
        [YEAR]

FROM table

GROUP BY [Main Artist], [Station Code], [Year]
```

And then pivoting this result in Excel to do the sums, but I was unsure of how to incorporate it into a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate the 2 values and then
`COUNT` the `DISTINCT` values:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(TrackTitle,'|',MainArtist)) AS [Count],
       Station,
       [Year]
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Station,
         [Year];
```

Comment: Will count the track "Forever Young" by the artist Elsa as the same as "Forever" by "YoungElsa".

Comment: I'll add a pipe, *just* for you, @jarlh ...

Comment: Duh, I guess I was overthinking it - The concat definitely seems a lot simpler than the multiple temp tables I was making.

Answer (score 3):

Remove duplicate rows in a *derived table* (i.e. the subquery). `GROUP BY` its result:

```
select count(*) cnt, station, year
from
(
    select distinct * from table
) dt
group by station, year
```